# Google Tag Manager Events Fire in Debug mode but no data in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

So, I'm just a lowly developer that isn't to all of this SEO stuff. So, I'm grasping at straws here.

I set up a test GTM and Analytics account for a test domain I have yesterday. I added the GTM tag code to the `<head>`of my _Layout.cshtml so it's available for every page.

I can see the Tags fire in GTM Debug mode, as well as the data layer pushes, but no data is reflected in real time or historical reports.

Please let me know if there is something wrong with my setup, or if there's something else I need to check.

GTM Classic Google Analytics Tag:

[image: GTM Classic Google Analytics Tag]

GTM Universal Analytics Tag:

[image: GTM Universal Analytics Tag]

GTM Trigger Configuration:

[image]

GTM Variables:

[image]

GTM Debug DataLayer Results:

[image]

Google Analytics ECommerce:

[image]

The only Google code I have placed on my site is the GTM tracking code. No custom data layer pushes as of yet or anything that should be remotely complicated.

I can see the analytics.js and ga.js scripts pull down successfully in Chrome's Network tab.

Did I miss something?

Comment: NOTE: I can also see the variables and fields being set correctly in the GTM Debug as well.

Comment: In your classic Ga tag you have entered the page Url variable in the field for the tracking id. This will not work. Also it seems doubtful that you need both a classic and a universal tag. Check your GA settings variable if you have set your tracking id (property id) correctly, it should be in the format UA-XXXXXX-XX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eike was correct. I set the property ID incorrectly. Why that's an option in the first place, I have no idea. But updating it corrected the problem.